# Pointcuts for intercept assignment of annotated fields

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm writing a simple auditing framework which allows me to audit the fields of a class which are annotated with an @Audit annotation.

Example of possible annotations

```java
class User {

    @Audit
    private String phoneNumber;

    private String name;

    @Audit
    public getName(){
        return name;
    };

    public setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

So far I was only able to define a simple pointcut that watches calls to setters annotated with the @Audit annotation:

```java
@Pointcut("call(* @Audit set*(*))")
```

How does a pointcut look that watches the assignment of fields that are annotated like in the above example?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is [not possible with SpringAOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) at the moment,

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans). Field
>   interception is not implemented, although support for field
>   interception could be added without breaking the core Spring AOP APIs.
>   If you need to advise field access and update join points, consider a
>   language such as AspectJ.

If You were to use AspectJ, you can use [`set(FieldPattern)`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#primitive-pointcuts) pointcut. There are some examples in [The AspectJTM 5 Development Kit Developer's Notebook](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#signaturePatterns)

`set(@Audit * *)` seems to work,  as for `set(* @Audit * . *)` - I'm not sure, perhaps AspectJ recognizes first wildcard as field modifiers but according to docs first element is annotation, second is modifier...

Comment: Actually I'm not using Spring AOP. This is a pure AspectJ Solution :)

Comment: Im not shure how the set field pattern would look like. I tried this one set("* @Audit * . *") but it did not seem to work... do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Zounadire try this `set(@Audit * *)`

Comment: i removed the space in my first suggestion and it worked :D `set(* @Audit *.*)`. what is the difference compared to your suggestion?

Comment: Ok tried yours too both work, but is there difference? do they both adress the same set of fields? Btw. put your suggestion in the answer so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this solution to work.  Can you help me apply it here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592018/can-i-use-an-annotation-to-modify-a-annotated-property?noredirect=1#comment80137516_46592018