# Can I use an annotation to modify a annotated property?

Tags: java, groovy, aspectj, aspect

Given

```
class MyPOJO {
    @XssSanitized()
    String name
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface XssSanitized {

}

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect

@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
class XssSanitizedAspect {

    @Around("@within(com.es.phoenix.services.security.XssSanitized))")
    void sanitize(){
        //capture the value of the annotated String
        //make an arbritary change to the string
        //return modified string or otherwise overwrite the property
            log.info("XssSanitizedAspect is working!!!!")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to modify the property `myPOJOObject.name` inside of `XssSanitizedAspect`?

In reality, I need a way to XSS sanitize `String` properties.  I tried creating a custom Jackson Deserializer.  It worked, but I cannot [inject a feature toggle](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/685) (without a workaround that breaks all the contracts with the UI) so that solution failed me.

I've gone through numerous examples online.  I have not found an example where the annotated property has it's value directly modified in such a way.

Comment: Is this actual AspectJ? If so, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133857/7470253) should help.

Comment: Yes.  `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect`.  Modified question.  Will look at your suggestion.

Comment: I _think_ something like     `@Around("set(@XssSanitized * * )")` should get you going. but I cannot test it at the moment. I base this assumption on the docs: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#d0e1170

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, no, I meant to ask if those annotations meant to be processed by actual AspectJ weavers. Certain AOP implementations, such as Spring's, support only a subset of AspectJ capabilities. If you're using SpringAOP, then you will be forced to use setter methods instead of field access.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - honestly I don't know.  If there's something I can check please let me know. I'm using Spring.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to take a step back and describe precisely what you want to achieve. The signal to noise ratio in this question is pretty high. What is the event you want to trigger the advice (i.e. the pointcut part)? What do you want to happen when it's triggered (the advice part)?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete - What precisely is noisy or unclear?  The question states precisely what I need to achieve `In reality, I need a way to XSS sanitize String properties.`.  And the example code shows the boilerplate of what needs to be done to get there.

Comment: Well, the only question that you've got in your post is actually this: _Is it possible to modify the property myPOJOObject.name inside of XssSanitizedAspect?_. Well, the answer to this is very simple, you can change the `name` attribute of `myPOJOObject` the same way as you would do from a regular class, if access rules allow it (or you can make your aspect privileged to work around this limitation). But I believe this is not the answer you're looking for. I think you're looking for something else and you should clarify it by changing your original post.

Comment: What I _think_ you actually want to ask is: "Is it possible to intercept assignments to all instance variables marked with an annotation to change the value that gets assigned to that variable?", though I can only speculate as to what you intend to do as your question is not clear _to me_.